# Drag and drop with PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, user-interface, drag-and-drop, pysimplegui

Is it possible to create a "drop files here" zone on a window?

A method mentioned in this old issue works, though only with Qt and Input element. I wonder if there's a better solution.

https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/732

Upd: Created an enhancement request

https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/6051